# Clone record issue

Tags: apex, trigger, class, button

I am facing a problem regarding Clone of record. I have an apex page as detail page of Survey__c object. There is a clone button to create new record from existing one via an apex class. Now I am not allowed to modify that Apex class or clone button. There is no way track kept which is the master record and cloned record. How can I figure out now the master and slave record of Survey__c object?

Please help me out.

Comment: question is not clear at all. Please, put some code and what have you tried to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query for **created date** for both records and whichever has later date that is cloned.